# How can I always show the main page when I click the tab bar in swift4?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the code to go to the next page and show the tabbar when I click the button.

```
@IBAction func moveBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextPage") as? nextPageCon else {
            return
        }
        self.definesPresentationContext = true
        next.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
        self.present(next, animated: false)
    }
```

My question is, when I go to another page using the tab bar on the next page and then return, I want to show the main page.

Currently, when I move using the tab bar and then come back, the next page is displayed as it is.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `nextPageCon` view controller:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

When you present `nextPageCon` and then navigate away by selecting a different tab, this func will trigger and dismiss itself.